# Updater mechanism in Inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

I'm searching a way to auto update an application when a new version is available. In our case the installer will be called for starting the application. When an update is available it will auto download and install it and start the application itself.

Can this behaviour be created in Inno Setup?

Comment: I want to use inno setup itself as launcher that starts before the application itself. Inno will check for updates and update when one update is available. After installing/updating the software it need to start the application itself. It would also be nice to show the user an splashscreen when inno setup checks for updates.

Comment: My plan was to have one global installer that only install the application with the launcher and after that the launcher will take the responsibility to update the applicatin itself. All of this need to run without admin rights but an installation in the user profile folder isn't a problem.

Comment: Or one inno setup that will copy hisself to the users local drive and to the stuff of the launcher itself

Comment: Because the launcher only need to check for updates and update it.

Comment: I will find another way for the launcher. But the updater/installer I will implement in Inno Setup. Can you help me starting with it?

Comment: How to download a zip file and unzip it during the installation